# sf@size not defined, but \textsuperscript works?

Tags: fonts

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\show\@textsuperscript
\show\sf@size
\makeatother

A\textsuperscript {B}C

A{\selectfont{${^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@ B}}}$}}C

\end{document}
```

The log shows:

```
#1->{\m@th \ensuremath {^{\mbox {\fontsize \sf@size \z@ #1}}}}.
l.6 \show\@textsuperscript

> \sf@size=undefined.
l.7 \show\sf@size
```

How would I perform the `\textsuperscript` macro in the raw, without invoking the macro? Trying to learn some TeX!

---

**UPDATE**: Thanks to answer from Kruger, this works as expected.

Now, the question is why the raw invocation shows a bigger font size for the superscript compared to `\textsuperscript`?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to answer from Kruger, all complete!

It's been a fascinating rabbit hole!

Final answer: `\ensuremath` sets `sf@size`. Details in accepted answer.

```
A\textsuperscript {B}C

\makeatletter
A$\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@ {\selectfont B}}}}$C
\makeatother
```

Comment: To ask a follow up question, you should create a new question instead of editing the existing one. Otherwise the existing answers often no longer make sense and the edit does not receive a lot of attention.

Comment: Please edit your question into a question (and such that the accepted answer makes sense as an answer to the question), not as something that starts with an answer. (I've done part of this for you—put the updates at the bottom—but consider whether the updates may be better as an answer, or removed, or left in the question.)

Comment: The final code is a complicated version of `A$^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont B}}$C`. And no, `\ensuremath` does *not* set `\sf@size` as part of its job; it's a side effect of doing a math formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\sf@size` is the fontsize for the script math fonts. It depends on the current regular text fontsize, so it has to be recalculated for every block of math. This is done with `\everymath`: If you add `\show\frozen@everymath` to your document, you see that `\frozen@everymath` is set to `\check@mathfonts \the \everymath`.
This means that everytime you enter inline math, TeX executes `\check@mathfonts` first. This macro sets `\sf@size` and does some other stuff. This also happens when `\ensuremath` enters math mode, which is the case for your `\textsuperscript` example.

So to `\show` `\sf@size`, it has to be set first by writing `$ $` to enter (and leave) mathmode somewhere before `\show\sf@size`.

By the way, if you want to understand how the LaTeX commands are implemented, look at [`source2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e). Apart from not having to  `\show` all the macros separately you also see a lot of comments describing the functionality there.

To perform this without invoking the macro, you need two changes: First `\makeatletter` is required to allow using `\sf@size` (and `\z@`) in a document.
Then you still get the wrong fontsize. This is because `\fontsize` does only set the next fontsize, but does not actually change the font. So `\selectfont` has to be invoked to select the font in the right size after `\fontsize\sf@size\z@`. In the macro, the call to `\selectfont` is inside `\textsuperscript` (without the `@`). In `source2e` the documentation of `\@textsuperscript` even contains a note that the argument should always start with a font selection command,

Comment: Kruger . How did u know that `\sf@size` is for script math fonts? What sorcery? Teach me? Is it found at source2e?

Comment: Kruger. I managed to somewhat mimic the macro in raw TeX. However, the font size is different? Any clues?

Comment: If you search for `\sf@size` in `source2e`, you can find it in `\getanddefine@fonts` where it is used to select the `\scriptfont`. The TeXbook explains that `\scriptfont` selects the font for the math script style.

Comment: @Kruger . Thanks for your additional answer. Gosh, I missed that fact (too many brackets in LaTeX!). I would've created a separate question for you, but didn't think StackOverflow allows "_really dumb questions resulting from unnecessary human error_".

Comment: @Kruger Can u pls answer this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428395/sfsize-has-no-effect-though-set-by-ensuremath

Comment: @Kruger Can u pls answer this question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428397/how-do-i-learn-latex-tex-inside-out