# sf@size has no effect, though set by ensuremath

Tags: fontsize

I'm unable to get `\sf@size` to work. It's set by `\ensuremath`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
sf@size: {\ensuremath \sf@size}
\makeatother

A\textsuperscript{B}C

\makeatletter
A$\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@ B}}}$C
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: (BTW the answer to your question is that after `\fontsize\sf@size\z@` you need `\selectfont` for the font change to take effect… as done by `\textsuperscript`.)

Comment: Wanted to separate out my question from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427538/sfsize-not-defined-but-textsuperscript-works .

Comment: »It's set by `\ensuremath`.«  What do you think `\ensuremath` does?